# List files in dropbox folder

Tags: php, json, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

Im having problems with the dropbox API.

When i try to get the metadata for my folder, i get the data output like this:

```
{"hash":"10f86b5b7c9c9276501f67a71ecd41c9","thumb_exists":false,"bytes":0,"path":"\/","is_dir":true,"size":"0 bytes","root":"app_folder","contents":[{"revision":7,"rev":"7069e0896","thumb_exists":true,"bytes":19749,"modified":"Tue, 20 Mar 2012 05:06:43 +0000","client_mtime":"Mon, 26 Sep 2011 11:50:43 +0000","path":"\/1_sml.jpg","is_dir":false,"icon":"page_white_picture","root":"dropbox","mime_type":"image\/jpeg","size":"19.3 KB"},{"revision":6,"rev":"6069e0896","thumb_exists":true,"bytes":15797,"modified":"Tue, 20 Mar 2012 05:06:43 +0000","client_mtime":"Mon, 26 Sep 2011 11:51:09 +0000","path":"\/2_sml.jpg","is_dir":false,"icon":"page_white_picture","root":"dropbox","mime_type":"image\/jpeg","size":"15.4 KB"},{"revision":5,"rev":"5069e0896","thumb_exists":true,"bytes":13349,"modified":"Tue, 20 Mar 2012 05:06:43 +0000","client_mtime":"Mon, 26 Sep 2011 11:51:26 +0000","path":"\/3_sml.jpg","is_dir":false,"icon":"page_white_picture","root":"dropbox","mime_type":"image\/jpeg","size":"13 KB"},{"revision":4,"rev":"4069e0896","thumb_exists":true,"bytes":8838,"modified":"Tue, 20 Mar 2012 05:06:43 +0000","client_mtime":"Mon, 26 Sep 2011 11:51:46 +0000","path":"\/4_sml.jpg","is_dir":false,"icon":"page_white_picture","root":"dropbox","mime_type":"image\/jpeg","size":"8.6 KB"},{"revision":3,"rev":"3069e0896","thumb_exists":true,"bytes":99646,"modified":"Tue, 20 Mar 2012 04:57:58 +0000","client_mtime":"Tue, 20 Sep 2011 14:14:26 +0000","path":"\/bg.jpg","is_dir":false,"icon":"page_white_picture","root":"dropbox","mime_type":"image\/jpeg","size":"97.3 KB"}],"icon":"folder"}
```

My problem is that i would like get the output for each the image/file name only.. But i can find the right way to do it.. i through i could do it this way:

```
$info = json_encode($dropbox->getMetaData(''));
foreach($info->contents->path as $file){
    echo $file;
}
```

But i get this error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/djrasmusp/rasmusp.com/db/index.php on line 16
```

But is there anyone that can give me a helping hand with my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `json_decode` instead of `json_encode` (and maybe use second parameter to produce associated array instead of `stdClass`).

Comment: then i get this error message:

Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/djrasmusp/rasmusp.com/db/index.php on line 15

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/djrasmusp/rasmusp.com/db/index.php on line 16

Comment: var_dump($dropbox->getMetaData(''));?

Comment: found the problem i hade to write:
foreach($info['contents'] as $a){} instead of foreach($info->contents as $a)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, here is my solution:

```
$metaData = $dropbox->metaData($path);

foreach($metaData['body']->contents as $file){
    $f = str_replace("/", "", $file->path);
    echo "<li>$f</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tested by me :)

```
require_once('bootstrap.php');
$metaData = $dropbox->metaData();
foreach($metaData['body']->contents as $file)
{ 
   echo "<pre>";
   echo $file->path; 
}
```