# List the names and Urls of the files from folder of dropbox using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropbox

I am trying to list the names and URLs of all files from the folder and subfolders of Dropbox. I found the following code snippet that [Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper) proposed in a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647082/is-there-a-way-to-import-a-list-of-files-in-a-dropbox-folder-into-google-sheets):

```
function dbxFileUpload(files) {
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(getGlobal('GPSTracksFolderId'));
  var fileBlob=UrlFetchApp.fetch(files[0].link).getBlob();
  var file=fldr.createFile(fileBlob);
  var fi=formatFileName(file);
  var fileInfo={'name':fi.getName(),'type':fileBlob.getContentType(), 'size':fileBlob.getBytes(), 'folder':fldr.getName(), 'id':fi.getId()};
  return fileInfo;
}
```

I am not sure how to use this snippet in my situation. The other sources that could provide solutions are in different languages i.e. Php, Android.

[Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40634475/connect-a-google-app-script-to-dropbox?rq=3)

[Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546153/list-all-the-folder-and-files-of-dropbox-using-dropbox-api)

[Source 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546388/list-all-the-dropbox-files-and-folder-using-dropbox-api-and-download-file-clicke)

[Source 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782207/list-files-in-dropbox-folder)

I have already created a Dropbox app that provides `App Key` and `App Secret`, but due to my beginner skills, I am not sure how to make it work using Google Apps Script. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the file list of your Dropbox using Dropbox API with Google Apps Script.

**In order to use Dropbox API, it is required to use the access token. In this answer, it supposes that you have already had your valid access token. Please be careful about this.**

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, the file and folder list are retrieved from your dropbox.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const accessToken = "###"; // Please set your access token.
  const path = "";

  const url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder";
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: "post",
    headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken },
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify({ path, limit: 2000, recursive: true })
  });
  const obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  console.log(obj);
}
```

- When this script is run, the following result is obtained. In this case, both files and folders under the subfolders are included.

  ```json
  {
    "entries": [
      {".tag": "###", "name": "###", "path_lower": "###", "path_display": "###", "id": "id:###"},
      ,
      ,
      ,
    ],
    "cursor": "###",
    "has_more": false
  }
  ```
- If you want to retrieve the files under a subfolder, please set `const path = "";` as `const path = "/sampleFolderName";`. In the case of `const path = "";`, all files and folders in dropbox are retrieved.
- If `has_more` is `true`, please retrieve the next list using [list_folder/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue).
- Please check more information about this at "[list_folder of Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder)".

#### Note:

- In this answer, it supposes that you have already had the valid access token for using this API. Please be careful about this. If you want to know the method for retrieving the access token, please check the official document. ["Authorization" section of Ref1](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation) and [Ref2](https://developers.dropbox.com/ja-jp/oauth-guide)

#### References:

- [list_folder of Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder)
- [list_folder/continue of Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue)

### Added:

About the file URL, it seems that `{fileId}` of `https://www.dropbox.com/s/{fileId}/{fileName}?raw=1` is different from the file ID. So, I prepared one more sample script for retrieving the file URL. I think that the following script can retrieve it.

```js
function getSharedLink() {
  const accessToken = "###"; // Please set your access token.
  const fileId = "###"; // Please set file ID.

  const url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/get_file_metadata";
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: "post",
    headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken },
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify({ file: fileId })
  });
  const obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  const sharedLink = obj.preview_url;

  console.log(sharedLink);
}
```

- In this case, [get_file_metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_file_metadata) is used. If you want to retrieve the URL from the folder, please use [get_folder_metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_folder_metadata).

Comment: Thank you, I was able to generate an Access Token, but there is mention of a `Long-Lived`, or `Short-Lived` access token. Does this mean I have to generate an access token after a specific period of time? If yes, can we automatically generate new token every time or permanent token that will not expire?

Comment: @EagleEye Thank you for replying. About your reply, if you are talking about `token_access_type`, the official document says as follows. `If this parameter is set to offline, then the access token payload returned by a successful /oauth2/token call will contain a short-lived access_token and a long-lived refresh_token that can be used to request a new short-lived access token as long as a user's approval remains valid. If set to online then only a short-lived access_token will be returned. If omitted, this parameter defaults to online.`. If this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, one last thing, I put `file id` and `file name` in your suggested url `https://www.dropbox.com/s/{fileId}/{fileName}?raw=1` to get file url but it gives an error.

Comment: @EagleEye Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added one more sample script for retrieving the file URL. Please confirm it.

Comment: can you please guide If `has_more` is `true`, then how would the script looks like?

Comment: @EagleEye About your new question of `can you please guide If has_more is true, then how would the script looks like?`, I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question? If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?