# Getting files from subfolders of Dropbox folder using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropbox

This is a continuation of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77043476/list-the-names-and-urls-of-the-files-from-folder-and-subfolders-of-dropbox-using/77044626?noredirect=1#comment135883907_77044626) for which [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) proposed a very good solution to get files from a specific folder. However, it needs modification if there are subfolders in a specific folder. Here is sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const accessToken = "###"; // Please set your access token.
  const path = "/SampleName";

  const url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder";
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: "post",
    headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken },
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify({ path, limit: 2000, recursive: true })
  });
  const obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  console.log(obj);
}
```

The endpoint that will be used to get files from subfolder of a folder is:

```
https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder/continue
```

However, due to my basic skills, I need guidance to use this in the above script. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const accessToken = "###"; // Please set your access token.
  const path = "/SampleName";

  let url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder";
  let has_more = false;
  const option = {
    method: "post",
    headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken },
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify({ path, limit: 2000, recursive: true })
  };
  let values = [];
  do {
    const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, option);
    let obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
    values = [...values, ...obj.entries];
    has_more = obj.has_more;
    if (has_more) {
      url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder/continue";
      option.payload = JSON.stringify({ cursor: obj.cursor });
    }
  } while (has_more);

  console.log(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, when `has_more` is true, the list is retrieved from the next page using `cursor`.

#### Reference:

- [list_folder/continue of Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue)